# Displaying output text in labels without and action

Tags: vb.net

**Scenario:** The user sets the rates for the ticket categories.

```
adults=100  
children=200
```

There is a button labelled `continue?`. When he clicks on it, a new form opens.

In that form I need 2 separate labels like:

```
The rate for Adults is 100.  
The rate for Children is 200.  
"are you sure you want to continue?"
```

How can I achieve this?

my code is

```
Module Main_Module
Dim _adult As Decimal
Public Property adult() As Decimal
    Get
        Return _adult
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        _adult = value
    End Set
End Property
Dim _children As Decimal
Public Property children() As Decimal
    Get
        Return _children
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        _children = value
    End Set
End Property
Dim _nriadult As Decimal
Public Property nriadult() As Decimal
    Get
        Return _nriadult
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        _nriadult = value
    End Set
End Property
Dim _nrichildren As Decimal
Public Property nrichildren() As Decimal
    Get
        Return _nrichildren
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        _nrichildren = value
    End Set
End Property
Dim _camera As Decimal
Public Property camera() As Decimal
    Get
        Return _camera
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        _camera = value
    End Set
End Property
Dim _handycam As Decimal
Public Property handycam() As Decimal
    Get
        Return _handycam
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        _handycam = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Module

This is the main object module

This is form 2..... Here is where the users set values for the respective categories.

Public Class Rate_setting_page

```
Private Sub adultrate_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles adultrate.TextChanged
    adult = CDec(adultrate.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub childrenrate_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles childrenrate.TextChanged
    children = CDec(childrenrate.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub nriadultrate_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles nriadultrate.TextChanged
    nriadult = CDec(nriadultrate.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub nrichildrenrate_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles nrichildrenrate.TextChanged
    nrichildren = CDec(nrichildrenrate.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub camerarate_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles camerarate.TextChanged
    camera = CDec(camerarate.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub handycamrate_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles handycamrate.TextChanged
    handycam = CDec(handycamrate.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Rate_setting_page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: thank you for editing.....an answer would have been nicer...

Comment: Please show as your code and we will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to verify the users intention, why not use a MessageBox?

```
Dim adults As Integer = 100
Dim children As Integer = 200 ' have your own values here, of course!
If MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The rate for Adults is {0}{1}The rate for Children is {2}", adults, ControlChars.NewLine, children), _
                       "Continue?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        'continue
Else
        'abort
End If
```

You could of course create your own Dialog Form to do that (see the Dialog template in Visual Studio) but it seems to me this will suffice.

Why take a sledgehammer to crack a nut, if you can use a nutcracker?